# transform rows into columns in a pandas dataframe with serial data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot, transpose

I want to transform distinct rows in a dataframe into columns and the values assigned to each column.

I have a pandas dataframe with this structure (coming from a json file):

```
    Key        Value
0   _id         1
1   type        house
2   surface     156
3   county      andr
4   _id         2
5   type        apartment
6   surface     95
7   county      sprl
8   _id         3
9   type        house
10  surface     234
11  county      ilm
..
```

I expect a dataframe similar to:

```
     _id    type      surface   county
0    1      house     156       andr
1    2      apartment 95        sprl
2    3      house     234       ilm
...
```

Comment: `df.pivot_table(columns='Key', 
               values='Value', 
               index=df['Key'].eq('_id').cumsum(),
               aggfunc='first')`

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.read_json(your_json, orient='records')
```

This should read it in the format you want.